# linux mint 18 - pyglet not displaying image correctly (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint, pyglet

I recently installed Linux Mint 18 (previously using Ubuntu-Gnome).
I'm using pyglet and python3 to develop a card game and everything was going swell on Ubuntu but now, on Mint, my app isn't displaying correctly.
Since I'm still developing definitions and classes I tested a card on screen on Ubuntu - worked like a charm. On Linux mint it shows like in the screenshot. Am I missing some package??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdzT3.jpg

The background should be black and not..that :/
Can you help?

Comment: Please do not add solved in title, instead accept your answer, to learn more see [tour]

Comment: Would be neat if you gave us the code next time that you used to render this background and image :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it had to do with the default theme of Linux Mint Sonya. Probably due to transparency conflicts.